# Add column name to the column of a matrix

Tags: r

I am trying to add a column name to the column of a 10 column by 100 row matrix, test_matrix, which has each of its columns filled with 100 random numbers generated from runif()

```
test_matrix <- matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = 100)

for (i in 1:ncol(test_matrix)){
    test_matrix[, i] <- runif(100)
    colnames(test_matrix)[i] <- paste0("Column ", i)
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "Column 1") : 
length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent
```

Why does this not work?

Comment: What is `my_matrix`?  You defined `test_matrix`

Comment: Sorry about that (typo) - edited question.

Comment: I think you don't need a loop for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
test_matrix <- matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = 100)

colnames(test_matrix) <- paste0("Column", seq(ncol(test_matrix)))

> head(test_matrix)
       Column1 Column2 Column3 Column4 Column5 Column6 Column7 Column8 Column9 Column10
  [1,]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA
  [2,]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA
  [3,]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA
  [4,]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA
  [5,]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA
  [6,]      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA       NA
```

Comment: That works great, thanks. Why does naming by indexing column not work?

Comment: @JoshuaRosenberg Because `colnames` is not defined (equals `NULL`) when you start the loop, so you try to access the elements of an non-existing object. If you first define e.g. `colnames(test_matrix) <- rep("foo", 10)`, your loop works. (But of course the solution of mkemp6 is better.)